# XCode does not auto compile anymore after project get's bigger

Tags: xcode

In the beginning when I create a new project, XCode will see errors as I type and tries to correct me. However, when my project gets bigger, XCode will not auto compile anymore. Anytime I hit the build button, the errors will come up. I want to see the errors as I type. I got a macbook pro 2017 and XCode 9.2. These are my settings:

[image]

Trying to clean the derived data etc will not work

Comment: Sadly, that's an Xcode bug. Not much can you do about it except restarting Xcode/cleaning the project/deleting Derived Data - those usually solve it.

Comment: @the4kman pff it's soo slow... When I need to know my errors I need to manually recompile it...